# SAS: Delete all text after a character

Tags: text, sas, analytics, punctuation

I have a column of data, let's say it looks like this:

```
This is text: part 2
This is text
This is also text: part 3
```

I need to delete everything after the : so that all three rows of data will read:

```
This is text
This is text
This is also text
```

Does anyone know how to do this in SAS?  I typically remove punctuation, et al...but haven't yet had a need to delete everything after a character.

Any guidance would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The `SCAN()` function would work well for this.

```
want = scan(have,1,':');
```

The only issue might be if the text starts with a colon.  If the text starts with a colon (or multiple colons) then `SCAN(have,1,':')` will return the first block of text after the leading colons.  If you add the modifier 'M' to the `SCAN()` call then it will treat the extra colons as denoting missing values and return an empty string.

```
want=scan(have,1,':','m');
```

Comment: Could use `scan(have,-2,':')` if it might start with a colon, no?  Though that would then fail if it doesn't contain a colon... no ideal solution I guess without checking.

Answer (score 1):

```
data test;
a1='This is text: part 2';
a = substr( a1,1,index(a1,':') - 1);
output;
run;
```